# mysql complex procedure debugging

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have below stored procedure which i would like to debug but its not throwing any errors into error table.This stored procedure is run by event manager on every minute.

Here is the process :

I have four tables:  A, B,C,D

Whenever any data will be inserted into `table A` same time using `trigger` data will be inserted into `table b`. Here table b has all those columns which are available in `table A`.table D contain only latest date on which procedure has been ran.

Below is the procedure which is inserting data into `table C`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `abc`; 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `abc`(IN `last_execution_time` DATETIME, IN `end_date` DATETIME)
BEGIN
    DECLARE errorCode VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE cdrs_uniqueid text;
    DECLARE cdrs_staging_uniqueid text;
    DECLARE cdrs_staging_count varchar(5);
    DECLARE reseller_cdrs_count varchar(5);
    DECLARE reseller_cdrs_uniqueid text;
    DECLARE cdrs_count varchar(5);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
                errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        END;
        select count(`uniqueid`),group_concat(`uniqueid`) from  b where `end_stamp`>=last_execution_time AND `end_stamp` < end_date into cdrs_staging_count,cdrs_staging_uniqueid;
        select count(`uniqueid`),group_concat(`uniqueid`) from cdrs where `end_stamp`>= last_execution_time AND `end_stamp` < end_date into cdrs_count,cdrs_uniqueid;
        select count(`uniqueid`),group_concat(`uniqueid`) from reseller_cdrs where `end_stamp`>= last_execution_time AND `end_stamp` < end_date into reseller_cdrs_count,reseller_cdrs_uniqueid;
        INSERT INTO `c` (`account_id`, `reseller_id`, `type`, `country_id`, `billseconds`, `mcd`, `total_calls`, `debit`, `cost`, `total_answered_call`, `total_fail_call`, `unique_date`, `calldate`) (SELECT `accountid`, `reseller_id`, `type`, `country_id`, SUM(`billseconds`) AS `billseconds`, MAX(`billseconds`) AS `mcd`, COUNT(*) AS `total_calls`, SUM(`debit`) AS `debit`, SUM(`cost`) AS `cost`, COUNT(CASE WHEN `billseconds` > 0 THEN 1 END) AS `total_answered_call`, COUNT(CASE WHEN `billseconds`=0 THEN 1 END) AS `total_fail_call`, DATE_FORMAT(`callstart`, "%Y%m%d") AS `unique_date`, DATE_FORMAT(`callstart`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `calldate` FROM `b` WHERE `end_stamp`>=`last_execution_time` AND `end_stamp` < `end_date` GROUP BY `accountid`, `country_id`, `reseller_id`, `unique_date`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `billseconds`=(`billseconds` + VALUES(`billseconds`)), `debit`=(`debit` + VALUES(`debit`)), `cost`=(`cost` + VALUES(`cost`)), `total_answered_call`=(`total_answered_call` + VALUES(`total_answered_call`)), `total_fail_call`=(`total_fail_call` + VALUES(`total_fail_call`)), `calldate`=`calldate`, `mcd`=GREATEST(VALUES(`mcd`), `mcd`), `total_calls`=(`total_calls` + VALUES(`total_calls`));
        insert into debug_info(`query`,`type`,`operation`) values(concat('INSERT INTO `cdrs_day_by_summary` (`account_id`, `reseller_id`, `type`, `country_id`, `billseconds`, `mcd`, `total_calls`, `debit`, `cost`, `total_answered_call`, `total_fail_call`, `unique_date`, `calldate`) (SELECT `accountid`, `reseller_id`, `type`, `country_id`, SUM(`billseconds`) AS `billseconds`, MAX(`billseconds`) AS `mcd`, COUNT(*) AS `total_calls`, SUM(`debit`) AS `debit`, SUM(`cost`) AS `cost`, COUNT(CASE WHEN `billseconds` > 0 THEN 1 END) AS `total_answered_call`, COUNT(CASE WHEN `billseconds`=0 THEN 1 END) AS `total_fail_call`, DATE_FORMAT(`callstart`, "%Y%m%d") AS `unique_date`, DATE_FORMAT(`callstart`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `calldate` FROM `cdrs_staging` WHERE `end_stamp`>= "',last_execution_time ,'" AND `end_stamp` < "',end_date,'" GROUP BY `accountid`, `country_id`, `reseller_id`, `unique_date`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `billseconds`=(`billseconds` + VALUES(`billseconds`)), `debit`=(`debit` + VALUES(`debit`)), `cost`=(`cost` + VALUES(`cost`)), `total_answered_call`=(`total_answered_call` + VALUES(`total_answered_call`)), `total_fail_call`=(`total_fail_call` + VALUES(`total_fail_call`)), `calldate`=`calldate`, `mcd`=GREATEST(VALUES(`mcd`), `mcd`), `total_calls`=(`total_calls` + VALUES(`total_calls`))'),'cdrs_day_by_summary','insert');

        -- BELOW Entries are not inserted into debug_info table as well as not showing any errors into errors table.

        insert into debug_info(`query`,`type`,`operation`) values (concat("WHERE `end_stamp` >= '",last_execution_time,"' AND `end_stamp` < '",end_date,"' UNIQUEID : cdrs : ",cdrs_uniqueid," : reseller_cdrs : ",reseller_cdrs_uniqueid," : cdrs_staging : ",cdrs_staging_uniqueid," : COUNT : cdrs_staging : ",cdrs_staging_count," cdrs count : ",cdrs_count," : reseller_cdrs : ",reseller_cdrs),'cdrs_staging,cdrs','select');
        UPDATE `d` SET `last_execution_date`=`end_date` WHERE `name`='get_cdr_records';
          -- BELOW Entry also not inserted into debug_info table as well as not showing any errors into errors table.

        insert into debug_info(`query`,`type`) values(concat('update `reports_process_list` SET `last_execution_date`="',end_date,'" where `name`="get_cdr_records"'),'reports_process_list','update');
        IF errorCode != '00000' THEN
            INSERT INTO `errors` (code, message, query_type, record_id, on_db, on_table) VALUES (errorCode, errorMessage, 'insert', NEW.uniqueid, 'astpp', 'f');
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Anyone have suggestion to debug this procedure or modification into above procedure to get inserted information into debug_info table.

Comment: `INSERT (fields) (SELECT values)` is wrong. Remove excess parenthesis, must be `INSERT (fields) SELECT values`.

Comment: You shall try your insert / update commands in mysql client before making it into a stored procedure.

Comment: @NatarajanNNapoleon : I have tried in my local system before put into stored procedure even though i also monitored for some time from procedure and it was  working fine and then again its stop automatically

Comment: What do you want to happen if one instance is still running for a minute and the next instance starts?  Typically this leads to a meltdown after several minutes, sort of like a traffic pile up.

Comment: @RickJames : I don't think so one instance will ever take time than a minute and Actually this case will never come as it will grab data from a table which have never more than 100k records in 3 hours  .But still if we consider this will happen then not sure what is better solution for it.Can you please suggest  ?

Comment: Manually try `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and similarly for each other query in the SP.

Answer (score 1):

If the insert / update was successful in your local system and not in another server, then there is no point in discussing that it had run in your local system. You have to check using the server in which it fails.

If the insert / update was successful in the same server but in a mysql client and fails through stored procedure, you shall try this.

```
get diagnostics condition number
```

has to be run for each of your insert / update and then you can check value of errorCode.

Please refer document for

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION
```

And also for

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
```